# How to retrieve values from a DAO recordset dynamically?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a DAO recordset such as

```
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from EMPLOYEES")
```

The recordset has following fields - NAME, AGE, SALARY, TITLE

Now I have created an array with a certain list of fields -

```
     Dim Fields As Variant
     Fields = Array("NAME", "SALARY")
```

And want to retrieve the fields from the recordset dynamically using the array elements

```
     rst.MoveNext

     MsgBox(rst![Array(0)])
```

I get an error stating 'Item not found in the collection'.

I know what I am missing here is the proper way to pass the variable for the Field Name after the exclamation ('!') sign but I can't figure out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `rst.Fields(Fields(0)).value` and iirc you can use ordinals so better: `rst.Fields(0).value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rst!FieldName
```

That syntax is really syntax sugar for the following:

```
rst.Fields("FieldName").Value
```

In other words, by writing `rst![Array(0)]`, you're looking for a field that's named `[Array(0)]` - the part after the exclamation mark is taken literally.

Simply use the low-sugar syntax instead :-)

```
rst.Fields(Fields(0)).Value
```

Note that `Array` isn't the name of your array variable, so `[Array(0)]` isn't referring to `Fields(0)` as you probably thought it would (and `Array(0)` would be making a new array of values, containing the value `0`). If the name `Fields` is confusing, try this:

```
Dim fieldList As Variant
fieldList = Array("NAME", "SALARY")

...

MsgBox rst.Fields(fieldList(0)).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rst.Fields(Fields(0)) or rst.Fields(Array(0))
```